# DKIM Fail Domain Null

Tags: postfix, gmail, dkim

Mail signing failing for gmail. No idea why. It passes with Telnet but fails Mail command. Here is the original mail response:

```
Delivered-To: user@test.com
Received: by 10.100.177.142 with SMTP id j14csp1917050pjb;
        Tue, 2 May 2017 08:11:12 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.200.41.8 with SMTP id y8mr27532431qty.220.1493737872152;
        Tue, 02 May 2017 08:11:12 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <user@mpx.test.com>
Received: from test1.mpx.test.com (ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. [xx.xx.xx.xx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k43si17514690qta.19.2017.05.02.08.11.12
        for <user@test.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 02 May 2017 08:11:12 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@mpx.test.com designates xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender) client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@mpx.test.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@mpx.test.com designates xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@mpx.test.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=test.com
Received: from mongobkp3.test.local (mongobkp3.test.local [xx.xx.xx.xx]) by test1.mpx.test.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id D18F2611B2 for <user@test.com>; Tue,
  2 May 2017 15:11:11 +0000 (UTC)
X-DKIM: Sendmail DKIM Filter v2.8.3 test11.mpx.test.com D18F2611B2
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mpx.test.com; s=ggmx2; t=1493737871; bh=ehVmMHs7ThAQbbHJS1xFhiviXLfcCW/H8SCDhdqpBjk=; h=Date:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:
     Message-Id:From; b=nQANMdy69jSkfQW/jOaZqKsN8gLj5GhiH4CQv8NXy5orGi5eqVt4RpBnz2ZVlUdUX
     qrfZGXHR1YufY8Ij0IM6eZvlC8uP4H37N0ItKXkLSLMT2PZb2gkIL/QY+6ToKkkiWO
     n3HTj7HWpdWxIp8uXrLuX03080v38lgPD0nds3lg=
Received: by mongobkp3.test.local (Postfix, from userid 1085) id CC0AE41E78; Tue,
```

My master.cf looks like this:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd   -v
#  -o content_filter=dksign
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
587       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd   -v
#  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o content_filter=dksign
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# The Cyrus deliver program has changed incompatibly, multiple times.
#
old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
```

My main.cf looks like this:

```
# RR: Mon Apr 29, 2013 => added 72.172.71.2/32 to support (LA) Duo VPN
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = test1.mpx.test.com
mydomain = mpx.test.com
masquerade_domains = !jetsetter.com !parkandbond.com !testcity.com !testtaste.com !wsjselect.com !mx.test.com !qatools.test.com test.com $mydomain

mynetworks =
XX.XX.XX.XX
XX.XX.XX.XX
XX.XX.XX.XX
$myhostname
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
soft_bounce = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_mynetworks
smtp_generic_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/generic
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_application_name = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_enforce_tls = no
#smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/mx1-cert.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/mx1-key.pem
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
#smtpd_tls_security_level = may
mailbox_size_limit = 102400000
message_size_limit = 51200000
queue_minfree = 76800000
smtpd_client_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unknown_client
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_invalid_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unlisted_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unlisted_recipient,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain
# check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/filtered_domains
smtpd_data_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
  xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol = haproxy
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.mpx.test.com.tld.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mail.mpx.test.com.tld.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
#smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

**Update!:**
If I copy out smtp_generic_maps, then the dkim passes however the from domain in my email shows up as the host that it was sent from via my relay server. I'm wondering if there's something up with how the domain mapping is working:

```
(.*)@(.*)\.test\.local/        $1@mpx.test.com
```

Comment: Give us details about Postifx configuration.

Comment: Sure thing sir/madam!

Comment: And this is ok when you send email via  `telnet localhost 25` ?   What is your DKIM signing program, DKIM-filter for Sendmail?

Comment: I'm using Dkim-milter, and yes it works when telnet localhost, and Im sending mail using mailx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much troubleshooting I realized the issue lies in the mapping. When you receive an email from an external client to your relay server using mailx then in the `/etc/postfix/generic` file you can map to send the mail out as your domain. However an easier way to resolve the problem is when sending mail from the client using the -r option with mailx and specifying a sender as someone with the domain you want to send with. For example:

```
mailx -r testuser@<domainyouwant> -S "test" enduser@<whereever>
```

This will pass DKIM signing and be sent as the user you want to send as.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Google upped their required key length to 512.  Yours looks like 128.

https://blog.returnpath.com/google-is-failing-your-perfectly-good-dkim-key-and-why-thats-a-good-thing/

Edit:

Oh, Sorry.  The 128 was the SSL not the DKIM.  My mistake.

Can you capture the text of the conversation between the mail client and compare it to the text of your telnet tests?  That might be promising.

When you say telnet, do you specifically mean telnet or something ssl, like openssl s_client?  If your telnet test is in the clear, and your mail client is using SSL, might that have something to do with it?  Probably not.  That would be weird.

Comment: I'm using a 1024 bit key.

Comment: It also signs when I send via telnet.